# How Many cuRand States Required for Thread-Unique Random Numbers? (CUDA)

Tags: random, cuda, state

How many cuRand states are required to get unique random numbers in every thread? From other questions posted on the site, some have said that you need one per thread and others say you need one per block.

Does using one cuRand state per thread mean better random numbers? 
Does using 1 cuRand state per thread slow down CUDA applications significantly (5000 + threads)?

Also for the implementation of using 1 cuRand state per thread, does this kernel look right and efficient?:

```
__global__ void myKernel (const double *seeds) // seeds is an array of length = #threads
int tid = ... // set tid = global thread ID
{
curandState s;
curand_init (seeds[tid],0,0,&s)

....

double r = cuRand_uniform(&s);

...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all your threads stay synchronized, then you want to generate the random numbers in all threads as shown in your sample code all at the same time. However, from what I understand, you do not need to seed the cuRAND differently in each thread. I may be wrong on that one though...

Now, they use the term "block" in the documentation as in "create all your random numbers in one block". They do not mean that one block of threads will do the work, instead it means one block of memory will hold all the random numbers all generated in one single call. So if you need, say, 4096 random numbers in your loop, you should create them all at once at the start, then load them back from memory later... You'll have to test to see whether it makes things faster in your case anyway. Often, many memory accesses slow down things, but calling the generator many times is not unlikely slower as it certainly needs to reload a heavy set of values to compute the next pseudo random number(s).

Source:
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/host-api-overview.html#performance-notes2